# Gstreamer:: Usage of g_signal_emit_by_name

Tags: gstreamer

I am developing an application which plays H264 dump using gstreamer

The pipeline is: appsrc - h264parse - ffdec_h264 - ffmpegcolorspace - deinterlace - autovideosink

And data flow is :: PULL Mode from appsrc { using the signals: need-data}

I want to verify the same application using PUSH mode from application: In the documentation it is mentioned that: we need to invoke 'push-buffer' signals and send the buffers

My code snippet is:

```
gst_app_src_set_emit_signals(source, TRUE);
g_signal_connect (source, "push-buffer", G_CALLBACK (start_feed), source);
```

Though the pipeline is created, I am not getting any callbacks to : `start_feed()`

Can anyone help me, what exactly need to do for 'PUSH' mode operation of appsrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html#gst-app-src-set-emit-signals):

> Make appsrc emit the "new-preroll" and "new-buffer" signals. This option is by default disabled because signal emission is expensive and unneeded when the application prefers to operate in pull mode.

So, you could try adding a "new-buffer" signal. "push-buffer" is an action, so attaching a signal handler won't do anything because it's something you're supposed to call when you have data, not something that calls a callback.

Depending on what your `start_feed` does, you may also be looking for the "need-data" signal (presumably signals when the pipeline needs more data).

Comment: As per the document: Enabled the signals
gst_app_src_set_emit_signals(source, TRUE);
And added signal: new-buffer as: g_signal_connect (source, "new-buffer", G_CALLBACK (start_feed), source); but this is resulting an error saying: no signal named: new-buffer. If I am using 'need-data', it is as good as gstreamer pulling the data. My application works in live-streaming env and data will be better pushed rather than pull

Comment: @Kranti If you're just pushing data, why are you waiting for signals at all? Can't you just give it data whenever you have it?

Comment: Yes, true. But I have a doubt -- Can i create some thread & keep on calling appsrc_push_buffer() ? Because, from the documentation, it is mentioned pppsrc requires few signals for pushing data -- I was confused whether to push data directly without waiting for any CBs from pipeline.. Sorry, I'm a newbie.. dont know many aspects of gstreamer.. Thanks for your help..